# Performance issue with a Spring/Hibernate/Tomcat application

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, profiling

I am experiencing performance problems with my Spring/Hibernate/Tomcat application.

By profiling the app I noticed that some methods have an abnormally high selftime (I have included a screen capture of the CPU sample below).

[image: cpu sample screenshot]

I suspect it has something to do with my jpa configuration...

Here is my configuration:

```
public abstract class DataConfiguration {

    @Value("${database.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${database.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${database.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${database.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${database.validationQuery}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTestOnReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1800000);
        dataSource.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
        dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1800000);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(5);
        dataSource.setLogAbandoned(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernatePersistence persistenceProvider() {
        return new HibernatePersistence();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.bignibou.domain");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(persistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesMap());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    public abstract Map<String, String> propertiesMap();

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

}

@Profile({ Profiles.DEFAULT, Profiles.CLOUD, Profiles.DEV })
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
class DefaultDataConfiguration extends DataConfiguration {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> propertiesMap() {
        Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
        return propertiesMap;
    }

}
```

Notice the `org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take()` selftime...

Can anyone help?

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take() selftime is perfectly fine, that means tomcat threads are almost always waiting on the queue for the new http request task to come

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot JK1. I guess I'll have to look elsewhere to diagnose my app's performance issues...

Comment: You shouldn't have a method returning `EntityManager` as the `EntityManager` isn't thread-safe. Remove that method to get a fresh `EntityManager` when needed. Also in your config you ahve `hibernate.show_sql` and `hibernate.format_sql`, printing queries is slow so if you are peformance testing you want to make sure that those aren't on. Only setting the `jpaVendorAdapter` is enough you don't need the additional `persistenceProvider` as that is part of the `JpaVendorAdapter`. Also spring will call `afterPropertiesSet` for you so don't call it yourself.

Comment: Another thing to note is that you have max 5 connections in your configuration. So when there are more, those will block until a connection is available (or until the request for a connection times out). You are using a validation query on your connections make sure that you use a fast query.

Comment: @Marten: Thanks a lot for your input. How can I determine how many max connections to choose for my app? Is there any guideline or rule for that?

Comment: @Jk1: I meant  I'll have to look elsewhere **in my code**... :-)

Comment: Regarding max connections, here is an interesting link I found: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency

Comment: @balteo, it also worth taking a look at GC dynamics. Frequent garbage collections may significantly slow down the application.